# npm package.json - Use beta version conditionally?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Is it possible to use a beta version of a package in package.json based on the git branch you are working on?

For example:

If you are on the master branch the normal package is used/installed.
If you are on any other branch then the beta version of the package is used/installed.

Comment: Is it that you always want the latest beta to be installed on the other branches? Or a specific beta?